# Mongodb Sorting returns null instead of data

Tags: mongodb

My Mongodb dataset is like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a27cc4783800a0b284c7f62"),
    "action" : "1",
    "silent" : "0",
    "createdate" : ISODate("2017-12-06T10:53:59.664Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Now I have to find the data whose Action value is 1 and silent value is 0. one more thing is that all the data returns is descending Order.
My Mongodb Query is

```
db.collection.find({'action': 1, 'silent': 0}).sort({createdate: -1}).exec(function(err, post) {
            console.log(post.length);
});
```

Earlier It works Fine for me But Now I have 121000 entry on this Collection. Now it returns null.

```
I know there is some confusion on .sort()
```

If i remove the sort Query then everything is fine. Example

```
db.collection.find({'action': 1, 'silent': 0}).exec(function(err, post) {
            console.log(post.length);// Now it returns data but not on Descending order
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB **limits** the amount of data it will attempt to sort without an index . 
This is because Mongo has to sort the data in memory or on disk, both of which can be expensive operations, particularly for queries run frequently.

- **In most cases, this can be alleviated by creating indexes on the fields you sort on.**

you can create index with :-

```
db.myColl.createIndex( { createdate: 1 })
```

thanks !

Comment: How to create the index on particular field? In my cases how i can create the index

Comment: you can use same syntax i have given in anser, just change collection name as your keep other same, it will create index on "createdate" , which you want i think, you can change  field name on which you are doing operation as per your requirement.

Comment: check after creating index on "createdate" field it should work.

Comment: Running db.myColl.createIndex( { createdate: 1 }) returns error i,e Message.createIndex is not a function

Comment: Okay. I am using Mongoose. So may be thats the reason